# WSO2 3.0 Geo Location Statistics

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to generate geo location stats in WSO2 V3.0 but I am unable to get x-forwarded-for value in the backed API and I have used the following below code

```
<property name=x-forwarded-for expression=get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR') scope=transport/>
```

I am accessing the application like `http://IP:port/login` and in this case i should get my IP in the backend API but i am always getting localhost IP which is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: <property name="x-forwarded-for" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')" scope="transport"/>

Comment: So ur application calls the API gateway and both running in localhost? And you want the application users IP address for this?

Comment: Yes both running on my local machine but I am accessing/configured the gateway URL & application both using the IP not from the localhost so in this case i should get the IP...this is giving me no value <property name="x-forwarded-for" expression="get-property('axis2','x-forwarded-for')" scope="transport"/> which seems to be required for geo stats

Comment: When invoking the API from your APP, do u send the x-forwarded-for header in the request? For geo location, gateway gives the priority to the header value and not the client IP.

Comment: is it required to 'x-forwarded-for' in the header with IP? if yes then how i would get the know who is accessing the API ? I am assuming that gateway should handle it internally using <property name="x-forwarded-for" expression="get-property('axis2','x-forwarded-for')" scope="transport"/> in sequence tag... if some one is accessing my API from external which is outside application users then i can not ask them to send there IP in x-forwarded-for header...

Comment: I guess ur users access your application. And then the app calls the gateway. If this is the flow, your app should send the IP via a header. Otherwise, gateway cannot figure out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209707/discussion-between-deepak-and-pubci).

Comment: Can we show city name in geo location map ? if yes how ?